# SSH tunneling with ZeroTier network

Tags: ssh, zerotier

So i have ESXi in a server with ip 192.168.1.169
Inside ESXi i have a VM that has NextCloud and ZeroTier enabled

I used ZeroTier so i could use NextCloud outside of my network.

Now i need to access to ESXi Web GUI outside of my network and since i have ZeroTier up and running i could use that right?

So i setup ZeroTier on my laptop, connected to the same network.

Now i am trying to SSH Tunneling to that NextCloud Vm so i can Manage all other Vms just by going to the ESXi Web Gui outside of my home network.

But i cant do that and i dont know why ...

ESXi -> 192.168.1.169 (running in port 80)
Vm with NextCloud -> 192.168.1.170 (LAN) , 172.30.5.64 (ZeroTier IP)

To do the ssh tunneling i did

```
ssh -L 1337:192.168.1.169:80 mysshuser@ZeroTier IP of my Nextcloud VM
```

When i do that command and try to go to localhost:1337 , nothing happens ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found that the problem was the network i was in.

I was using my phone networking and for some reason my ISP blocks VPN connections using that networking.

I tested with an external network from another house and it worked fine